# Change Gamertag in MCPE v1.2.3

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Okay, so there’s this new update in Minecraft PE v1.2.3 where you can’t change your gamertage without an Xbox live account. I don’t have an Xbox account, and my sister somehow changed it but she won’t tell me how. Does anyone else know how?

Answer (score 0):

Yes: go to settings -> profile -> playername and change it! As EZ as that!

*sorry, my game is in German:*

[image]